An old funny heist movie
I have trying to find a movie I watched at my childhood. It was black and white; as far as I remember, it was funny; and the plot was that some guys were trying to rob their own company (not certain whether their own company or not); at the end the garbage collectors collected the sacks full of money (I think). Any ideas?
A related question: In another movie, perhaps a sequel, again an old heist movie, and at the end the bus carrying our guys gets off the road and standing on balance on the edge of a cliff (I think).
Any ideas?

Please ask two questions separately.  The second one by the way is "The Italian Job" (1969).

Thanks, iandotkelly. I would definitely would do so, but as I said, I somehow (from your reply I understand that mistakenly) thought that the second movie was a sequel to the first one, so it could be helpful to mention both of them.

And from the garbage bit, the first one could be the original Ocean's Eleven from 1960. But at the moment this is way too vague to answer properly. Do you at least know the country and approximate decade? Any other details?

I am quite certain that it was a US movie, 60s or 70s.

I think I've found it, sounds very similar. It's called Who's Minding the Mint? and here's the Wiki page for it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_Minding_the_Mint%3F
As for your other movie, that is definitely The Italian Job which is an absolute classic! surprising to find someone who hasn't seen it, I heavily recommend it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Italian_Job

Thanks a lot, Matthew. I watched the trailer at youtube, and an early scene strongly suggests that that is the movie I am looking for. As for the Italian Job, I am really ashamed because I watched the remake, and have the DVD of the original; I was planning to watch it some time!

hahaha, yeah the remake has a more serious tone to it despite the fact that about 95% of the film is in america. I'm sure you won't be disappointed with the original. And as for your heist movie I'll have to give it a try, looks interesting.
